# Ошибка AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'getvalue'

Tags: python, django, requests, python-unittest

Написал небольшой unit-test для проверки GET-запроса в Django и выдает эту ошибку, сам тест:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure()


class TestMainPage(TestCase):

    def test_main_page(self):
        resp = self.client.get('//')
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: Приведите в вопросе полный стек ошибки.